# Is there a way to use COPY on multiple files at once?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, copy, amazon-redshift

I am trying to find a way to move our MySQL databases and put them on Amazon Redshift for its speed and scalable storage.  They recommend splitting the data into multiple files and using the COPY command to copy data from S3 into the data warehouse.  I am using Python to attempt to automate this process and plan to use boto3 for client side encryption of the data

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
     aws_access_key_id='[Access key id]',
     aws_secret_access_key='[Secret access key]')

filename = '[S3 file path]'
bucket_name = '[Bucket name]'

# Uploads the given file using a managed uploader, which will split up large
# files automatically and upload parts in parallel.
s3.upload_file(filename, bucket_name, filename)


#create table for data
statement = 'create table [table_name] ([table fields])'
conn = psycopg2.connect(
host='[host]',
user='[user]',
port=5439,
password='[password]',
dbname='dev')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(statement)
conn.commit()


#load data to redshift
conn_string = "dbname='dev' port='5439' user='[user]' password='[password]' 
host='[host]'"  
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string);
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""copy [table_name] from '[data location]'
    access_key_id '[Access key id]'
    secret_access_key '[Secret access key]'
    region 'us-east-1'
    null as 'NA'
    delimiter ','
    removequotes;""")
conn.commit()
```

The problem is with this code is I think I would have to individually create a table for every table and then copy it over for every file individually.  Is there a way to get the data into redshift using a single copy for multiple files?  Or is it possible to run multiple copy statements at once?  And is it possible to do this without creating a table for every single file?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support COPY SQL clause.. PostgreSQL does support COPY SQL clause.. You sure you have tagged the correct database?.. Besides psycopg2 looks to be a python PostgreSQL database adapter for PostgreSQL.. i've changed the tag MySQL into PostgreSQL.

Comment: We are using a MySQL database and moving it over to Redshift which is based on PostgreSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redshift does support a [parallelized form of `COPY`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html) from a single connection, and in fact, it appears to be an anti pattern to concurrently `COPY` data to the same tables from multiple connections.

There are [two ways to do parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_splitting-data-files.html) ingestion:

- Specify a `common prefix` in the `COPY FROM`, instead of a specific file name.

In this case, COPY will attempt to load all files from the bucket / folder with that prefix

- OR, provide a manifest file, containing the names of the files

In both instances, you should split the source data up into an appropriate number of files of approximately equal size. Again from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_splitting-data-files.html):

> Split your data into files so that the number of files is a multiple of the number of slices in your cluster. That way Amazon Redshift can divide the data evenly among the slices. The number of slices per node depends on the node size of the cluster. For example, each DS1.XL compute node has two slices, and each DS1.8XL compute node has 32 slices.